# How do I change the formatting of numbers in an array in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a short code that rounds some numbers in a table and stores them in an array object. I would like to set a custom format for these stored numbers, however I am not sure how, as the standard formatting method does not work with arrays.

My code looks like the following:

```
Dim i as long
Dim x as long
Dim RoundedAmounts (1 to 26) as long
    
    for i = 1 to 26
      x= range("I44").offset(i,0).value
      if abs(x) < 150000
           RoundedAmounts(i)=0
      else 
           RoundedAmounts(i)=Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(x, -5)
      end if
     Next i
```

I am a newbie at coding, so I'm not sure if this is an obvious task, but I couldn't seem to find an answer on Google. Any help would me greatly appreciated!

Comment: Formatting generally applies to something you want to display. Where and how are you displaying these values?

Comment: So my rounding code above had some numbers that are rounded e.g. 300000. I would like to have these numbers in the form of million USD so with the previous example, $0.3mm i.e. 300000.

Comment: @SuperSymmetry my end goal is to build a sort of auto commentary that would use these rounded numbers from my array. I think this formatting step will be the last step then, when i am putting together the display. Thank you for your help.

Comment: "Store numbers in the format in which you need them" is the anti-Excel logic. Excel stores a number in its original and most elementary format. The underlying logic is that you don't care about the format until you see it. Perhaps the best example of this is a date/time value like 44057.733333321. You can display it as hh:mm:ss or hh:mm or dd mmmm, yyyy or just dddd value. Instead of storing all 57 varieties Excel enables you to store only one and decide about the display when you want to look at it. Same for numbers and their formats and rounded versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number and its representation are two distinct, very separate things.

Your array contains `Long` (32-bit signed integer) values, and that is everything you need if your intent is to store the *values* and not their *representation*.

If you need an array that contains the string representation (e.g. `$0.3MM` instead of `300000`) of these numeric values, then you can't store them into `Long`, you need a `String` for that.

Say you have a `numbers` array that contains `Long` integers. You could define a `formattedNumbers` array that contains `String` elements, and use the `VBA.Strings.Format$` function (and a bit of simple math) to format the numeric values any way you need; using a *format string* that looks like `$0.0MM` you could represent the value `300000` (divided by 1 million) as `$0.3MM` like this:

```
Dim formattedNumbers(1 To 26) As String
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 26
    formattedNumbers(i) = Format$(numbers(i)/1000000, "$0.0MM")
Next
```

But, you very rarely need the string representation of a number in a program's logic: most often, what you want is for your code to work with the raw numeric values, and then format these values at the very last possible minute, only when the user needs to see them.

If that's the case, then you don't need a string array; you simply use the output of `Format$(numbers(i)/1000000, "$0.0MM")` wherever you mean to display that string value; some `TextBox` control, for example.

If your output is actually a worksheet cell / a `Range`, then you can write the numeric value into the cell (divide it by 1 million if you mean to display millions), and then set the cell's `NumberFormat` property to custom-format the numeric value as per your requirements.

Comment: Great answer! The only thing is a `Long` number in vba is a 64-bit signed integer value as mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/long-data-type

Comment: @SuperSymmetry thanks! but no, that's the .NET documentation. `Long` is a 32-bit signed integer in VBA and VB6 =)

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks for clarifying. I always assumed it was 64-bit as in most programming language.

Comment: @SuperSymmetry yeah, it is - except VB predates 64-bit processors by quite a bit, and saw the introduction of 32-bit processors in the 16-bit era! `Integer` is thus a 16-bit signed integer type (`short` in other languages), `Long` is the 32-bit type (`integer` in other languages), and `LongLong` was introduced in VBA7 to support 64-bit integers on 64-bit systems (`long` in other languages).

Comment: Many thanks for the info: I guess I have never needed an integer that doesn't fit in 4 bytes in vba :)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks for the outstanding answer, I'm in total awe from this community! My end goal here is to create a Commentary that can be copied for numbers that are in a table, so in my case storing it as a string would be preferable. Thank you for the clarification though!

Comment: What is the difference between `format` and `format$` ?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This should store formatted strings for you

```vb
Sub FormatedVals()
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim vRoundedAmounts As Variant
    
    ' copy into a 2d value (26 rows and 1 column)
    vRoundedAmounts = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I45:I70").Value
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(vRoundedAmounts, 1)
        If Abs(vRoundedAmounts(i, 1)) < 150000 Then
            vRoundedAmounts(i, 1) = 0
        Else
            vRoundedAmounts(i, 1) = Round(vRoundedAmounts(i, 1) / 1000000, 1)
        End If
        vRoundedAmounts(i, 1) = Format(vRoundedAmounts(i, 1), "$0.0") & "m"
    Next i

End Sub
```